# Printing the maximum value for each list in a nested list

Tags: python, list, max

I have a list of integer lists:

```
l = [[4,5,6,7],[3,4,5,6],[10,2,3,4]]
```

The output I am looking for is as below:

```
List 0
4 
5 
6 
7 Max value
List 1
3 
4 
5 
6 Max value
List 2
10 Max value
2 
3 
4
```

The code that I came up with is :

```
for i in range(len(l)):
    print "List",i
    for p in l[i]:
        print p if p!=max(l[i]) else p,"Max value"
```

But this yields a slightly different output with the Max value coming up in every case:

```
List 0
4 Max value
5 Max value
6 Max value
7 Max value
. 
.
.
```

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
l = [[4,5,6,7],[3,4,5,6],[10,2,3,4]]
for idx, items in enumerate(l):
    mx = max(items)
    print "List {}".format(idx)
    for item in items:
        print "{}{}".format(item, " Max value" if item == mx else "")
```

**Output**

```
List 0
4
5
6
7 Max value
List 1
3
4
5
6 Max value
List 2
10 Max value
2
3
4
```

Answer (score 4):

It's a precedence problem. `"Max value"` isn't associated with the `else` clause; rather, it's interpreted as a second argument to the `print` statement, and the `else` just contains `p`. There's no way to write a print statement where the number of arguments varies based on a condition, but you can disambiguate it with some tweaking:

```
for i in range(len(l)):
    print "List",i
    for p in l[i]:
        if p == max(l[i]):
            print p
        else:
            print p, "Max value"
```

Comment: Why you extract sublist by index - and not using enumerate?

Comment: @volcano: That's how the OP did it. I went for minimal change to the original code (and screwed up the first version).

Comment: my point is that extracting list elements by index in a loop is very un-Pythonic, and (don't take it as offense) you've missed the opportunity to show Pythonic way to do the stuff.

Answer (score 0):

```
ix = 0    
for lista in l:
        print "List ", ix
        for item in lista:
            if item == max(lista):
                print item, " Max Value"
            else:
                print item
        ix += 1
```